# Tornado Error In database.py line 58 - NameError global name 'CONVERSIONS' is not defined

Tags: python, tornado

I'm trying to run the Tornado Demo 'Blog'. I've changed the database options in the blog.py file. but when i try to run the blog.py file i get the following error!![image]

[blog.py file link](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/blog/blog.py)

[database.py file link](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/database.py)

What needs to be done to get past this error??

Answer (score 6):

I met the same problem. If you're using Ubuntu, try "`sudo apt-get install python-MySQLdb`"

Answer (score 1):

Install [MySQLdb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python) (required by tornado.database).